# How to determine if a given reaction requires heating to initiate?

Tags: physical-chemistry, energy, heat

At room temperature, some reaction propagate merely upon intermixing the reagents (e.g. [autoignition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature) of [triethylborane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triethylborane)), while others require additional heat to initiate (e.g. [crystallization of calcium chloride](http://solutionsguide.tetratec.com/index.asp?Page_ID=734&AQ_Magazine_Date=Current&AQ_Magazine_ID=2238)).

How can I determine if a given chemical reaction would require heating above room temperature to initiate? And to what temperature?

Answer (score 1):

The ease of initiation of a reaction depends on the [activation energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy) required. In order for reactions to proceed (at a reasonable rate), the forces binding the individual reactants must be overcome, which may require energy, solvent, catalyst or other input.

For example, $\ce{H2O2}$ is quite stable at room temperature, but exposure to horseradish peroxidase, silver oxide or other catalyst causes **rapid** decomposition. Iron filings do not oxidize quickly, but apply a bit of salt water and they rust so quickly they make an effective heater. [$\ce{NI3}$ has an **extremely** low activation requirement!](http://www.iflscience.com/chemistry/extremely-reactive-substance-blows-touch-feather/)

Comment: In your H2O2 example it seems that the thermal energy at room temperature is enough to overcome the activation energy. Was there a way for you to know this without trying out in an experiment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to study the reaction kinetics as a function of the species concentrations and temperature.  To quantify the behavior, you need to know the reaction mechanism, and then quantify this mathematically in terms of reaction rate expressions and reaction rate constants.  Experimental measurements then establish the values of the reaction rate constants as a function of temperature.